# Get filenames from opendialogform in a string vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, filenames

How can i get all the filnames in array as a string?

```
Dim paths As Array
Dim npaths As String

od.ShowDialog()
paths = od.FileNames
npaths = ArrayToDelimited(paths, ",")
```

Comment: A comma is not a good choice, it is a valid character in a file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx):

```
npaths = String.Join(",", paths)
```